# extract list after specific keywords in string python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have string

```
my_string = "K1:s1,\ns2,\ns3,\n\nK2:g1,\ng2,\ng3,\nK3:m1,\nm2,\nm3"
```

Simplified view of `my_string`:

```
"K1:s1,
 s2,
 s3,

 K2:g1,
 g2,
 g3,    
 K3:m1,
 m2,
 m3"
```

I need to look for keyword K1:,K2:,K3: and extract everything that comes after and before another keyword in a list.
for eg:

```
List1 = [s1, s2, s3]
List2 = [g1, g2, g3]
List3 = [m1, m2, m3]
```

The order of keyword in a string is not fixed. K1: can come after K2: and K3: and vice versa. And also the number of newline character '\n' is not fixed.

Is there any simple regex way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Is it mandatory to use regex?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use a regex and split on words.

```
result = []
for word in re.split('\W+', my_string):
    if word.startswith('K'):
        if result:
            print result
        result = []
    else:
        result.append(word)

if result:
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use regex to do that. All you need is to reformat and sort your input string based on the `K` values:

```
my_string = "K1:s1,\ns2,\ns3,\n\nK2:g1,\ng2,\ng3,\nK3:m1,\nm2,\nm3"
# Reformat and sort results.
my_string = sorted("".join(my_string.split()).replace(",K","\nK").split('\n'), key=lambda elem: int(elem[1]))
# Get results.
resultList = [elem[3:].split(',') for elem in my_string]
# Print results.
print(resultList)
```

Output:

```
[['s1', 's2', 's3'], ['g1', 'g2', 'g3'], ['m1', 'm2', 'm3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I consider whether i can extract value, which contains space or something else(except `\n`,`:`).

1. `[kK]\d+.(.*?)(?=.[kK]\d+|$)`

   - `[kK]\d+.` string begin with `k1:` or `K1:` or `k23:`
   - `(.*?)`  all match
   - `(?=.[kK]\d+|$)` string end with the end of whole string or `K1 k1`
2. `[^,]+` split string

Full code

```
import re

my_string = "K1:s1,\ns: face2,\ns3,\n\nK2:g1,\ng2,\ng3,\nK3:m1,\nm2,\nm3"
my_string = my_string.replace("\n","") # remove \n

string_list = re.findall(r"[kK]\d+.(.*?)(?=.[kK]\d+|$)",my_string,re.DOTALL)
group = [ re.findall(r"[^,]+",ele) for ele in string_list]
print(group)

# [['s1', 's: face2', 's3'], ['g1', 'g2', 'g3'], ['m1', 'm2', 'm3']]
```